# How to add access control in buildkite for repository/pipeline level?

Tags: buildkite

My organization deploy source code on github org account and uses `Bulidkite` as CI/CD tool. Any one who has access to `Buildkite` project can trigger a build for any repository pipelines. Is there a pipeline/repository access control in `Buildkite` to allow only selected users to trigger a build and make it readonly for other users? Ideally, I'd like to put the access control list on `pipeline.yml` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think about it, you can not put that ACL into a pipeline.yml file, because then everyone has write access to it so it is zero effort to break it. Buildkite has team setup so the administrator can define the permission for a group of people so that they either can observe or build or manage a pipeline.